# git gui doesn't clone using ssh, then i've to enter password and username everytime i do push

Tags: git, macos, github, git-gui

how can i configure git to force ssh until not possible!

If I check remote by doing:

`git remote -v`

they are all `https://....` urls and not

`ssh:...`

which would relief me from typing passwords every time.

Comment: Is ssh protocol enabled on the server? Have you tried `git clone ssh://....`?

Comment: github has ssh so yea

Comment: i can clone fine manually by typing `git clone sshurl`, and then i dont need to type credentials everytime

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/), Git can cash your credentials.